# Unable to access UIImageView image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Currently attempting to access a `UIImage` property of `UIImageView` to instantiate another `UIImage` object. Simply I'm trying to do this.

```
UIImage *myImage = myExistingView.image;
```

The property will not set however. I keep getting nil values for myImage.

I would like to copy the image, eventually doing something like

```
UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

but I can't seem to get it down. Suggestions?

Edit. Most recent attempt that has not worked.

```
UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image)]];
```

Comment: a little more code might help

Comment: where do u wanna copy the image !! i see there is no problem with the code you posted ... you can test if it hold the image like this 
UIImage *image =myExistingView.image;
    
    UIImageView *imagev =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    [targetimageview setImage:imagev.image];

Comment: Where/how do you set the image for myExistingView?

Comment: You might want to `NSLog` (or set a breakpoint and examine the variables) of `myExistingView` (e.g. has it been released already or something like that). But clearly either `myExistingView` or it's `image` has been released at some point. By the way, you most recent attempt clearly won't do anything if `myImage` is `nil`. You need to solve that core problem first. You may need to share more code with us regarding where you create and manipulate `myExistingView` and its properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Initialize your UIImage in this way `UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"imgCheckSelected.png"];`

After you will pass myImage to newImageView.  I`m not sure that you can save a UiImage inside another UIImage.

Comment: I'm not attempting to save one image inside of another UIImage, I'm attempting to do a copy of the image. The image is already loaded into a UIImageView from a url.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for accessing images

```
UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
```

It will dispaly image.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it works..

```
UIImageView *someNewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourExistingView.image];
someNewImageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150);

[self.view addSubview:someNewImageView];
[someNewImageView release];
```

Notice that `yourExistingView` is an `UIImageView` propertie added in Interface builder.

Have you checked the frame of your new `UIImageView`??
did you set the image in `yourExistingView`??
did you add the new imageview to view??